# what is difference between packet_ops_spkt and packet_ops

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, archlinux, linux-mint

Can anybody please help me difference between packet_ops_spkt and packet_ops structures operations.Where is used  packet_ops_spkt and how to use packet_ops. This both structures having Linux kernel source code under source/net/packet/af_packet.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google it and for your reference,

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/packet/af_packet.c#L2788

If sock->type is SOCK_PACKET then use the packet_ops_spkt stucture

The SOCK_PACKET is used to write raw socket, if you create socket with SOCK_RAW type.

http://www.masterraghu.com/subjects/np/introduction/unix_network_programming_v1.3/ch29lev1sec4.html

Comment: Thank you very much your support

Comment: I am using for creating socket following API socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_DGRAM,0x86dc) can you please help which can interact in kernel level ( packet_ops_spkt or  packet_ops)

Comment: Not sure what you mean... the socket you use shall use packet_ops_spkt as its operation functions. If you read from the socket fd, you should get the buf without LL header. I guess 0x86dc is the protocol you self-defined and want to capture or filter by this socket.